# Download and upload to Sync Database MySql with Sqllite

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

[image]

### Question

1)isn't it possible sync MySQL With Sqlite? or any better database synchronization ?
2)I m new on Android, What Method i should use on Android? any special method to sync database?

Comment: Using api you can do syncing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a REST API calls on the server to return both a schema version number and a last updated timedate stamp(server TS). If the client is out of date,the get only the updated changes from server and save it to your local DB.

Synchronization algorithm for exchanging data in the “Client – Server” model via REST API

[Link here:](http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html)

Comment: is that possible just sync a few table, not all the database scheme ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Microsoft Sync Framework toolkit`. Its for syncing the delta changes.

[Here](http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/) is a sample project

and read [this article](http://robtiffany.com/sync-framework-v4-is-now-open-source-and-ready-to-connect-any-device-to-sql-server-and-sql-azure/).

Comment: Sorry, my server is Ubuntu 12.04, i dont think so able to use Microsoft application?